# Get app names and version with BASH and Plistbuddy

Tags: mac, bash

I'm trying to feed the Application directory into an array and then use `PlistBuddy` with the entries to retrieve version info about each application that are installed.  Currently it seems to be not separating the list into individual array entries.

```
    apps=$(ls /Applications)
        for i in "$apps"
            do
                 /usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c Print:CFBundleShortVersionString: "$i"/Contents/info.plist
            done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not creating an array. `apps` is a string that contains the result of `ls /Applications`. Anyway, you don't need the ls, try something like this:

```
for i in /Applications/*
 do
  /usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c Print:CFBundleShortVersionString: "$i"/Contents/Info.plist
done
```

Comment: Isn't info.plist usually written with uppercase I?

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, fixed. I don't have a Mac so I just copied directly from the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

Some applications didn't have a CFBundleShortVersionString key. You could also use defaults or search for applications with mdfind:

`IFS=$'\n'; for f in $(mdfind kMDItemContentType=com.apple.application-bundle); do printf %s "${f##*/}:"; defaults read "$f/Contents/Info.plist" CFBundleShortVersionString 2> /dev/null || defaults read "$f/Contents/Info.plist" CFBundleVersion 2> /dev/null || echo; done`